# finding the range between two columns in one dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Year   Month  Day   High   Low
1999    2      2      10     5
1999    2      3      11     4
1999    2      4      NA     NA
1999    2      5      11     5
....    ..    ..      ..     ..
```

I want to calculate the range (the difference) between `High` and `Low` for every row and assign it to a new column, with NA values not counted.

My desired output is:

```
    Year   Month  Day   High   Low   Range
    1999    2      2      10     5     5
    1999    2      3      11     4     7
    1999    2      5      11     5     6
    ....    ..    ..      ..     ..    ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `na.omit` to remove `NA` values and add column with `transform`

```
transform(na.omit(df), Range = High - Low)

#  Year Month Day High Low Range
#1 1999     2   2   10   5     5
#2 1999     2   3   11   4     7
#4 1999     2   5   11   5     6
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(High) | !is.na(Low)) %>%
   mutate(Range = High - Low)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete.cases` in `base R`

```
transform(df[complete.cases(df),], Range = High - Low)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[complete.cases(.SD)][, Range := High - Low]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(across(c(High, Low), ~ !is.na(.))) %>%
     mutate(Range = High - Low)
```